Does anyone know what the Starship 5 fins are made of?
I was just wondering what material it’s made of.

Starship is made out of stainless steel and it the wings are also stainless steel. Are you asking about the heatshield on the wings?

I'm assuming you mean any of Starships SN 8 – S 33. SN 5 did not have flaps, it was just a tank with a payload simulator and sone engines.

In my best Carl Sagan voice: star stuff!

Do you mean Starship SN5 or the Starship used for flight 5?

Someone does.  Otherwise, they couldn't have made it!

are you asking about grid fins on booster or flaps on starship?

It's really unclear if you're asking about the 4 flaps on Starship (the upper stage) or the 4 black grid fins on the Super Heavy Booster.  I believe the grid fins are titanium alloy, just like on Falcon 9.  One of the Everyday Astronaut video tours w/ Elon has the answer for certain if you're asking about the grid fins.

@pbristow I was asking about the black grid fins on the super heavy booster. Thanks!

The Starship is completely made of stainless steel. This applies to the entire structure, the tanks and skin (note that those are the same thing: Starship does not have any kind of skin or insulation on the tanks – the tank walls are the skin), the aft engine skirt, the nose cone, and the flaps.
It is not fully clear what alloy of steel SpaceX uses. They started with 301L, then did use 304L for most of the time starting with SN 8, but there was also talk of them developing their own alloy dubbed 30X. We haven't heard anything about that for a long time, though, but it is not clear what that means: it could mean they gave up on it, it could mean they succeeded and it has already been implemented, it could mean they are still working on it, or it could mean they re-prioritized the work and paused it but will pick it up later.
The wall thickness seems to be uniformly 4  mm. Again, there has been talk of reducing wall thickness, and rolls of thinner steel (3.6  mm and 3  mm) have been spotted around the construction site and test tanks have been built (e.g., SN 7.2 with 3  mm walls), but it is currently believed that these experiments are on pause and Starship is still built of 4  mm thick steel.
As SpaceX transforms the little dirt field where they used to build vehicles in the open on the side of the road into a "proper" mass-production rocket factory, it becomes harder and harder to spot internal changes to the vehicles. Deliveries that used to be unloaded and stored on the side of the road with their shipping labels clearly visible are now delivered to dedicated storage, ring welding and dome sleeving happens inside the Starfactory, vehicle stacking happens in the high bays and mega bays, which have received doors to protect the vehicles and workers from the weather. So, unfortunately, such changes are a lot less obvious than they were in the beginning of the program.

An anecdote from Isaacson's biography: "The line workers said they thought the tank walls could get as thin as 4.8 millimeters. 'What about 4?' Musk asked. 'That would make us pretty nervous,' one of the workers replied. 'Okay,', Musk said, 'let's do four millimeters. Let's give it a try.' It worked."
